# WLAN: WLAN 2.4G, WLAN 5.1G, WLAN 5.8G?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I recently searched about cellphones and in device specs it states about wlan 2.4Ghz, 5.1Ghz and 5.8Ghz. I knew about 2.4Ghz wifi and 5Ghz wifi and the newer 6Ghz wifi(i think it is still under development). Then what is wlan 5.1G and 5.8G??

Comment: I recently became aware the 5g WiFi band is actually 2 bands between 5 and 6ghz (there are routers that claim to be triband using 2.4ghz + 5ghz - 5 ghz). I expect this is separating the 2 5 gig bands in its specs.

Answer (score 0):

5.1 GHz: Originally intended for indoors only and has the lowest EIRP limitations. It is not available in most parts of the world for outdoor use. Same EIRP rules for AP and client.

5.8 GHz:

- Smaller area of coverage, but usually better speed
- Many devices do not have 5.8 GHz available
- Best way to achieve optimum WiFi performance
- Less range may require more access points for large areas
- Can cause connection issues if all devices are not running on 5.8 GHz
- Preferred for gaming and file streaming because of speed

The 2.4 GHz radio runs on a lower frequency between 450 Mbps or 600 Mbps. The 5.8 GHz radio can support up to 1300 Mbps. That’s a pretty big difference in wireless speed. The 5.8 GHz band provides a smaller range of coverage but typically transmits data at faster speeds.

For your reference:

[2.4 GHz vs 5 GHz WiFi](https://www.sabaitechnology.com/blog/24-ghz-vs-5-ghz-wifi/)